# New Desktop Computer, Internet SLOW but We pay for 65mbps

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, performance, windows-firewall

I'm so confused, my internet on my new lenovo k450 is incredibly slow, speed test is  reading 1.15mbps (on average).  We pay for 65mbps (I believe) with comcast - this is what the connection speed says when I look at the connection in the network connection center.   I have one OLDER laptop that is getting speeds over 20mbps...the rest of the devices on the network are generally running slow, but not as slow as my desktop!  Our router is pretty old, but not too old...and if my laptop is running these speeds why aren't my desktop?  I'm planning to reset the router complete, but I do feel it's a setting on the desktop somewhere.  Could it be the firewall ?  I also don't understand how my firewall doesn't have Google Chrome on the list of allowed devices, but I run chrome all the time.  I want to add it to the white list, but I don't know if this will allow any network in through Chrome?  Any advice please!

Comment: It can't be the hardware internet speeds are not determined by your hardware unless your not in full duplex mode.  Browsers don't need a firewall exception most of the time

Answer (score 1):

If it were a firewall problem, no traffic would be getting through at all. Have you checked you router's sync speed for internet? Login to you router via 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1 and check the router connection status. There it should have upstream/downstream connection statistics along with line attenuation and SNR margin which should tell you if it's a service problem, modem problem or a PC problem.

Post these here if you want and I can tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Wireless networks were never meant to replace wired networks. While they do a decent job of supplementing and complementing existing wired networks, they'll never be as fast or as reliable. If this is a desktop, run a network cable to the modem and/or router and run your tests again.